# Grails 2.4 - domain modelling

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.4 and working with providing REST API. I am looking for suggestions on domain/entity creation.

I have 4 simple tables:

```
1) projects:
   projectId (auto-increment, PK)
   name 
   description
   (some other fields but not important for my question I guess)

2) users:
   userId (auto-increment, PK)
   roleId (FK->roles/roleId)
   username 
   (some other fields but not important for my question I guess)

3) project_users (join table for projects & users):
   projectId FK->projects/projectId)
   userId (FK->users/userId)

4) roles:
   roleId (auto-increment, PK)
   name
```

Role can be user or manager or admin. A project can have many users (multiple users of role 'user' and 1 user of role 'manager').

The consumer of this REST API (JSON) needs is list(GET)of Projects with names of all users (username not userId) for each Projects (all users.. does not matter if the user is manager  not). They also want to ability to add new users (PUT) to project. Also create new Project (POST). For all requests JSON request/response should contain username)  I am really looking for suggestions on how to proceed.

To get familiar with Grails/REST, I have defined 3 domains (projects, users and roles) and GET & POST JSON to these domains individually are working just fine (not domain relationship is done).

Then to play domain relations, I have tried 'db-reverse-engineer' plugin and it gave following domains with relationships.

```
class Projects {
    String name
    String description
    static hasMany = [userses: Users]

    static mapping = {
        id column: "project_id"
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        name unique: true
        description nullable: true
    }
}

class Users {
    String username
    Roles roles
    static hasMany = [projectses: Projects]
    static belongsTo = [Roles]

    static mapping = {
        id column: "user_id"
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        username maxSize: 32, unique: true
    }
}


class Roles {
    String name
    static hasMany = [userses: Users]

    static mapping = {
        id column: "role_id", generator: "assigned"
        version false
    }
    static constraints = {
        name maxSize: 16, unique: true
    }
}
```

Now I am not sure how to proceed further. Do I need to create a database view (db doesn't allow updates to view) & a corresponding controller and for save write custom code. It is only couple of days I am playing with Grails & REST, so bear with me for basic question.

Answer (score 0):

The general strategy for Grails development is a simple MVC pattern, where you have a controller build your model and pass it to a view.  For a REST API, you don't really need a view unless you need to change the default way your domain objects will be displayed.  You will need to configure some mappings for your requests which for REST APIs is discussed [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#urlMappings).  Beyond that all you need is a controller and a service if you need in any business logic beyond basic crud operations.  As for you domain layer, a couple of recommendations:

1) It's common to have domain classes and DB tables that matter be singular so you avoid having to have names like userses and so on.  So I would make your tables User, Role and Project.

2) You have a many-to-many relationship with your users and projects so you'll need to specify that.  You can do this with a joinTable in your mapping though you may want to make a separate domain class for ProjectUser if you are querying the relationship a lot as you'll run into the hibernate n+1 problem if you're not careful.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Grails by default uses Hibernate to interact with whatever database you're using. Their interface to Hibernate is called GORM (Grails object relational mapping). This is a powerful way to map your objects to the DB without having to muck around with DB views, stored procedures, and such. By default, Grails will even build the tables for you. Basic CRUD (Create, Read, Update, and Delete) actions are exactly what Grails is good at out of the box. I would recommend reading the [Grails user guide](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.0/guide/index.html) (specifically the [section on domain modeling](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.0/guide/GORM.html#domainClasses)) to get a better idea of the benefits of Grails.

Note: in case I sound like a shill, I will state uncategorically that Grails is pretty immature and has flaws for sure. It just so happens to be that quick and easy CRUD is exactly what it's good at.